# Why does this integer parity optimization fail in GLSL?

Tags: integer, logic, glsl, parity

I am using GLSL to draw axes with GL_LINES. It works, but the optimization below fails.

Correct rendering:

[image]

This is constructed from 6 lines, each starting at (0,0,0), are directed outwards, and have 2 attributes:

- `flat int f_parity` is 0 on the positive axes and 1 on the negative axes
- `float f_parameter` is 0 at the origin and `+N` at the furthest extent.

Working fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

     in vec3  f_colour;
flat in int   f_parity;
     in float f_parameter;

out vec4 out_colour;

void main ()
{
    if (f_parity == 0)
    {
        if (int (floor (f_parameter)) % 2 == 0)
            out_colour = vec4 (f_colour, 1.0);
        else
            discard;
    }
    else // f_parity == 1
    {
        if (int (floor (f_parameter)) % 2 == 1)
            out_colour = vec4 (f_colour, 1.0);
        else
            discard;
    }
}
```

Since `f_parity` is 0 or 1, and this always agrees with the right-hand-side of the expression, these logical branches can be merged using `int (floor (f_parameter)) % 2 == f_parity` as follows:

```
void main ()
{
    if (int (floor (f_parameter)) % 2 == f_parity)
        out_colour = vec4 (f_colour, 1.0);
    else
        discard;
}
```

But this only renders the positive axes.

[image]

Why do these produce different results?

Comment: `f_parity` is set to 0 or 1 in the vertex buffer.